# Fortran error when trying to install scipy

Tags: python, scipy, fortran

I'm trying to install scipy with Pip, using:

`sudo pip install scipy`

I throw this error, though:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libisl.13.dylib

  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.1.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/5.1.0/f951

  Reason: image not found

gfortran: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program f951)

error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c -c /private/tmp/pip-build-WaJ_GP/scipy/scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.f -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/private/tmp/pip-build-WaJ_GP/scipy/scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.o" failed with exit status 4
```

When I run:

```
brew install gcc
```

I get:

```
Warning: gcc-5.1.0 already installed
```

What gives?

Comment: Do you have `libisl` installed on your system?

Comment: Yes.. uninstalled / reinstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling (with `--force`) and reinstalling dependencies fixed the issue. (gmp, mpfr, libmpc, isl, cloog)